# How to insert a YouTube video in Dspace?

Tags: dspace

I have several items that have a video associated with youtube, the idea is that when displaying the item information in dspace interface JSPUI, the video is currently embedded, create a metadata (dc.identifier.video) to save the url of the video.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I wanna insert video preview, not only video URL

Answer (score 0):

First, I highly recommend you to use `local` schema for your custom metadata, i.e. video URL. For example, you can define `local.video` for this purpose. Now, let me go to your question. If you open a Youtube video page, by clicking **Share**, a dialog is opened. In the dialog, if you click on **Embed** you will have an `iframe` HTML code like the following:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rs9w5bgtJC8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

As you see, the value of `src` is `https://www.youtube.com/embed/rs9w5bgtJC8` that is the Youtube video URL. If you place the above `<iframe>` element in your item page in DSpace, you see the Youtube video embedded in that page. Therefore, you need to get the whole `<iframe>` code in which the `src` value is replaced by the value of `local.video` metadata.

#### UPDATE

The preview feature of DSpace is for previewing **bitstreams** and DSpace does not provide a preview of a video that its URL is stored in a metadata field. For your requirement, you need to customize DSpace.

Comment: I know the manual way you indicate, I'm interested in an automatic way that automatically dspace a metadata is placed in the URL of the resource

Comment: You mean your question is that how you can customize DSpace code?

Comment: I don't want to modify the code, is there any way that dspace natively uses the metadata value as the source of an iframe?

Comment: This feature is not available natively.